# Android API 23: intent-filter not working

Tags: android, android-intent

My app is registering an extension "myapp" so we can import file from email or inside the My Files app. It has been working before, but now it has stopped working. The app in the Play Store cannot see the files with those extension any more. The problem seems to start with Android Marshmallow, Android 6, API 23. The Play Store app works on Android 4.1.

Here is our code to register for intent-filter. What could possibly go wrong? 
Something is wrong with Stackoverflow, I cannot post my code, so I took a picture of it

[image]

Comment: what is ur host website to which ur app is connecting??

Comment: it is a local one. User will tap on a file in the local file system and it will open my app

Comment: U have not mentioned The port, and in the host ur using asterisk

Comment: @AvinashRoy I am doing a local file, I don't have to enter the host and the port, from what I understand

Comment: is it throwing any error??

Comment: No, it is not. Android just says that there is no app to handle this file type. If I am trying with pdf, it doesn't list my app in the list of handlers

Answer (score 0):

Starting from API-23,To enable your app to handle links, use intent filters in your app manifest to declare the URI patterns that your app handles.

The following example shows an intent filter that can handle links to http://www.example.com and https://www.example.com:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
    </intent-filter>
```

When the android:autoVerify attribute is present, installing your app causes the system to attempt to verify all hosts associated with the web URIs in all of your app's intent filters. The system treats your app as the default handler for the specified URI pattern only if it successfully verifies all app link patterns declared in your manifest.

Comment: but we don't have a link. We only want to open a file with a specific extension, like pdf file